# Hiding DataTable div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I'm trying to remove multiple divs with content inside one div and I'm getting to a point that I'm about to give up because I can't do nothing,

```html
<!--this div loads when the page is loaded, I can't find this code in my file) I extracted this from google dev tools) -->
<div id="table_wrapper">
  <div class="table-header">//filters</div>
  <div class="table">//table info</div>
  <div class="table-footer">//more filters</div>
</div>
```

I just want this

```html
<div id="table_wrapper">
  <div class="table">//table info</div>
</div>
```

I already tried some solutions but the result is the same (nothing happens)

## 1

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.table-header').remove();
    $('.table-footer').remove();
});
```

## 2

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".table-header,.table-footer").hide();
});
```

## 3

```css
div#table_wrapper .table-header, .table-footer {
     display: none!important;
}
```

I don't know what can I do more, I use

```
console.log("script #2: %o", document.getElementById("table_wrapper"));
```

to see if there are many changes but everything stays the same.

Comment: Please add [mcve] here in stackoverflow so that it's accessible without clicking random urls outside this site.

Comment: Well your formatting of the HTML only has one closed `div` there SO do you JUST want that div removed or it AND its content (the next  divs)?

Comment: I only want to remove "row-datatables-header" and "row-datatables-footer"

Comment: as you have the HTML your "header" contains the "footer".  Please update your question with proper HTML AND what javascript you have tried.

Comment: @MarkSchultheiss I don't know that much javascript because I'm still studying the basics and I don't have that much time to study javascript at the moment

Comment: Manually remove it then?  This frankly is NOT a well formed question an since you have no time we probably cannot help you invent time.

Comment: If I remove it from the css or js file that it is located I lose my other table so I can't do that

Comment: And I said I don't have time to study javascript so there is a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this in your style.css

```css
.no-footer .datatables-header, .datatables-footer { 
    display: none; 
}
```

Comment: Should I create another style.css with that piece? Because I'm using that class in another page.

Comment: Now I update that answer. please try that...If the problem exists please inform...will help u...

Comment: I tried to put that inside `<style>` and it's not working , but if I put `display: none!important` in chrome dev tools on those divs they disappear but in my code I just don't know where can I put that..

Comment: Do you have any tips?

Comment: What's your problem now??? Whether the div's got hide or not?? please explain clearly

Comment: I think I was clear, I tried the codes that I've put in the post and I still can't hide it or remove it. The result is nothing..

Comment: Do you have any suggestion ??

Comment: where you added this css??div#table_wrapper .table-header, .table-footer {
     display: none!important;
}

Comment: I tried in a style.css (didn't work) and in a style tag (didn't work) but if I put display: none!important in the google dev tools it works ! I have no clue how can we do this

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193394/discussion-between-ui-developer-and-joao-neves).

Answer (score 1):

```
$(".row-datatables-header,.row-datatables-footer").hide();
```

Comment: I will take a look at that in a moment, thanks by the way!